# Sum of (n) generated input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch

im using Lightswitch for my Application, and i have a question you might can answere:

I generate via Lightswitch DYNAMICALLY Input fields:

```
screen.Zeiterfassung_Position.addNew();
```

and ive got another readonly input field in which i want a sum of all input fields that are generated dynamically, how do i do that?

Is there any easy way? Thank you anyway!

Comment: Loop through them and add their values. Exactly how you do that would depend on your HTML.

Comment: For this you have to code......!

Comment: Getting a sum out of some object's property in an array of objects is the most common use case for *reduce()*: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Comment: i know i have to code but im a "newby"! :D, i dont want a finished code, i need to code by myself but didnt knew exactly how, i guess " Loop through them and add their values. Exactly how you do that would depend on your HTML. – Rory McCrossan 54 secs ago " could help a bit, thx anyway!